# iotop fields - What does 'TID' mean in iotop?

Tags: linux

What does `TID` mean in `iotop`?

```
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 3.90 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 2150 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 65.25 % [flush-202:0]
 6694 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s   19.64 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 6700 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s   23.56 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 8646 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s  424.12 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
10974 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s   19.64 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
```

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TID` stands for `Thread ID`, which for most purposes, you can think of as equivalent to the standard Linux `Process ID`.

Comment: i cannot see the value of TID when i check the output of ps aux or pstree . Am i not supposed to see the same value in TID of iotop and some process Id on my system ?

Comment: @kommradHomer you can always use `iotop -P`, that would print the PID instead. Credit goes to ananke on IRC.